# Using same code build files (with path information) on different computers via a VCS (Version Control System)

Tags: git, build, path

Let's say I have a package on my computer with some .cpp files in it. I compile and build these files. Now the newly created *build files* will contain instances of the **path** to my package or code.

I `git push` this package to my repo, and then `git clone` it on *another* computer. How do I work with this package, considering the **path will be different** - at the very least because of the different user account names - in multiple build files?

Thank you.

Comment: It's completely unrelated to git, git just makes snapshots. Like if you zip your files in archive in one computer and unzip on another. So better to investigate possibilities of your particular (package?) artifact you are building.

Comment: My understanding has always been that generated files (such as the build files) should *not* be stored in a version control system - only irreproducible items (such as source code, and *possibly* images etc.) should be.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using git I presume that all the code is contained in a single directory.

As a rule, files that can be regenerated by the build should *not* be placed under revision control. Because that will only generate unnecessary changes. List their names in a `.gitignore` file.

Then use a build system that doesn't use build files and doesn't depend on absolute paths, like [`make`](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), or [`scons`](http://scons.org/).